# How to change a apache rewrite rule to an irule

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, f5

On apache we have the following RewriteCond to block url's with a word in it.

```
<br/> 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} guest [NC]<br/>
RewriteRule .* - [F]<br/><br/>
```

How can we transfer this condition to an irule so we can put this on the F5 Loadbalancer?

Answer (score 0):

This will also create a log for each time the event occurs.

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
 if {([HTTP::uri] contains "guest")} { 
log local0.alert "Rejecting \"[HTTP::host][HTTP::uri]\"guest request from [IP::client_addr]" 
reject
} 
}
```

Comment: And do I need to use escapes if in the word/url are symbols like = or - ? so as an example user=guest

Comment: No, not if they are within the quotes - have a look here https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/irules-optimization-101-04-delimiters-braces-brackets-quotes-and-more and here https://cmdref.net/hardware/bigip/irule_sample.html  for more examples: